# Head on collision of 2 cars and vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, collision

I was reading about a head on collision of 2 cars.

The bad guy was going 90mph on the highway in the wrong direction.The good guy was doing somewhere around 65mph.

Using vector addition, is it theoretically okay to say that if the good guy sped up to 91mph and hit the bad guy, would the resultant vector act against the bad guy's favor?

Imagine that the 2 cars are 2 vectors. The angle between them is 180 degrees. Would the magnitude of the resultant vector end up in the good guy's favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be bad for *both* drivers since they both collide head-on with the same impact velocity. This is the sum of the velocity of each car.

As you have stated, velocity is a vector, and each car will impact the other with the resultant velocity (since they are both moving in opposite directions) $$\vec v_r=\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 =91 +65=156 \ \text{mph}$$

This is the impact speed experienced by each driver, and assuming that both cars and drivers are similar in every way, both will suffer the same amount of damage and injury.

Note that the total kinetic energy$^1$ released by the collision for both cars is the same $$T=\frac{1}{2}mv_r^2$$ so both cars/drivers experience the same impact.

$^1$ We also assume that the collision is completely inelastic, and both cars come to a compete crashing stop after the collision, which is a fair approximation.

Comment: From you r answer, it seems that the good guy is better of to come to a complete stop before the collision. That way, the resultant velocity will be lower.

Comment: Yes. If any driver decreases their speed, the same will be true.